# Error with Jest and React importing SCSS files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, tsconfig

I am writing unit test cases using Jest and my application is running with reactjs. I am trying to test a page component in my React application, but I am receiving errors that are shown in the following screenshot;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k71X5.png)

● Test suite failed to run

```
src/pages/unregistered/pep-login/login/login-layout.tsx:13:31 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../landing-new.scss'.

13 import * as stylesLayout from '../../landing-new.scss';
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

FAIL  src/pages/adu/dashboard/application-metrics/*test*/totalFailed.test.tsx
● Test suite failed to run

```
src/pages/adu/dashboard/application-metrics/total-failed-api-list.tsx:5:31 - error TS2307: Cannot find
```

module './application-metrics.scss'.

```
5 import * as stylesLayout from './application-metrics.scss';
```

Here is my package.json configurations

"jest": {
"collectCoverage": true,
"coverageDirectory": "target/testCoverage",
"collectCoverageFrom": [
"src/**/*.{ts,tsx}"
],
"setupFiles": [
"/config/polyfills.js"
],
"testPathIgnorePatterns": [
"/\\[/\\]"
],
"testEnvironment": "node",
"testURL": "http://localhost",
"transform": {
".(ts|tsx)": "/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js",
".+\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss)$": "jest-transform-css"
},
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
"[/\\]node_modules[/\\].+\.(js|jsx)$"
],
"moduleNameMapper": {
"^reac-native$": "react-native-web"
},
"moduleFileExtensions": [
"ts",
"tsx",
"js"
],
"testRegex": "(/**tests**/.*|\.(test|spec))\.(ts|tsx|js)$"
}
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gr5t.png)

Comment: Can you share your directory structure, maybe you're just using relative paths incorrectly?!

Comment: added image for directory structure

Comment: Directory structure relative to login-layout.tsx and landing-new.scss.